# Android memory leak when downloading or displaying multiple images

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks

I'm working on a directory app that looks similiar to the Contacts app on Android phones with the person's picture and their name beside it.  However, I need to get these images from the internet as long strings and convert them to images.

I am getting an "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget" after scrolling up and down the list of contacts a few times.

Is there something obvious in the code below that I should be doing different?

Downloading images as a string and storing in an asynctask:

```
//Image doesn't exist, need to add
  try {
      FileOutputStream fOut = (activity.getApplicationContext()).openFileOutput(guid, 0);
      OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
      osw.write(strImage);
      osw.flush();
      osw.close();
      contact.setImageLength(String.valueOf(strImage.length()));
      db.updateContact(contact);    
  } catch (IOException ioe) {
      ioe.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Displaying the images in the list adapter:

```
case R.layout.listview_member_row:

LayoutInflater inflater4 = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
row = inflater4.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

holder = new PositionHolder();
holder.txtName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.listview_member_name);
holder.imgPicture = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.listview_picture);

try {
    FileInputStream fIn = context.openFileInput(contact.getContactId());
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
    char[] inputBuffer = new char[Integer.parseInt(contact.getImageLength())];   
    isr.read(inputBuffer);
    String encodedImage = new String(inputBuffer);
    // Convert string to image 
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
    // Assign image to screen
    holder.imgPicture.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
} catch (IOException oe) {
    oe.printStackTrace();
}
row.setTag(holder);

holder.txtName.setText(listItem.name);
holder.txtName.setTextSize(nameTextSize);
break;
```

Comment: use lazy laoding if you are displaying images in listview

Comment: Can't lazy load... the images need to be available offline. I currently have them stored in external storage and their location saved in an sqlite db

Comment: you can cache images to your disk and display it offline. its possible.

Comment: The problem is that the app crashes a good amount of time after the list view is populated... I don't think this solves my problem.

Comment: i haves used lazy loading and it works for me. Why do you think it does not solve your problem?

Comment: I suspect this may be related to needing to call recycle() on Bitmaps when disposing/releasing/whatever the view that holds them. My understanding is that a chunk of bitmap data is stored in native memory, where the Dalvik vm garbage collector can't free it automatically.